# MySql error in C# after reading 100 lines from serial port

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a program that reads from a serial port. the program works fine but, after reading 100 lines from the serial port i get the following error.

An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

Additional information: error connecting: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

I really don't understand what does it mean.

thanks,
Sebastian

Comment: It has nothing to do with your serial port.  Fix the connection string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your program is opening a MySQL connection to a non-existent server behind the scenes (maybe in another thread) before reading from the serial port. The error you see is a MySQL connect timeout and is not related to serial operations.

**EDIT**: Your comment below gave me better insight about your problem. I think you're opening a new MySQL connection for each iteration of your loop and you don't close it properly, so after a hundred iterations your connection pool is full and you can't connect to the server anymore.

Try to open the connection *once* outside of the loop, then close it properly when your job's done. The [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28VS.80%29.aspx) statement is a good way to achieve that.

Comment: i have a local MySQL server, the and the program adds 100 entries in my MySQL database, after that i receive that error.
Any Ideeas?